# Integrating a matrix

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, integration, definite-integrals

Is it possible to integrate a matrix?

I've been working through a problem and come up with $$\int_{t_0}^t  \begin{pmatrix}\sin(s)\cdot\cos(\beta s)\\ \cos(s)\cdot\cos(\beta s)\end{pmatrix}ds$$

I'm integrating from $t_0$ to $t$

Can this be done or do we think I went wrong somewhere?

Comment: Isn't your integrand function simply $\;\tan s\;$ ...?

Comment: Did you mean $$\int \begin{pmatrix} \sin s & \cos (\beta s)\\ \cos s & \cos (\beta s)\end{pmatrix}\, ds$$

Comment: Ah, okay, doesn't matter much. Anyway, just integrate componentwise.

Comment: It's a 2x1 matrix. I'd be greftful if you could do the edit for me!

Comment: After the editing I see a $\,2\times 2\;$ matrix...

Comment: If you want to know whether you went wrong somewhere, you should tell us your initial problem.

Comment: Thanks @DanielFischer. So I'm able to simply integrate each component as it stands.

Comment: @Dominik Everything is fine if I'm able to do the integral. Cheers

Comment: @Steve Yes, integrating vectors or matrices is simply componentwise integration (as long as the dimension remains finite).

Comment: @DonAntonio The $sin(s)cos(\beta s)$ is the top term of the matrix, and the $cos(s)cos(\beta s)$ the bottom term.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Matrices form a vector space. Therefore, you can simply integrate them componentwise.

In detail. Let $A:t\mapsto A(t)$ be a function from a real interval $I$ to the space of $m\times n$ real matrices. 
Every entry $a_{ij}$ is a real function of a real variable. If all entries are integrable functions, then you can define the integral of the matrix as the matrix of the integrals:

$$\int A(t)\,dt := \left( \int a_{ij}(t)\,dt \right).$$

For your problem:

$$\int  \begin{pmatrix}\sin(s)&\cos(\beta s)\\ \cos(s)&\cos(\beta s)\end{pmatrix}ds = 
\begin{pmatrix}\int\sin(s)\,ds &\int\cos(\beta s)\,ds\\ \int\cos(s)\,ds&\int\cos(\beta s)\,ds\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-\cos(s)&\frac{1}{\beta}\sin(\beta s)\\ \sin(s)&\frac{1}{\beta}\sin(\beta s)\end{pmatrix}. $$

There is a more sophisticated operation, in case the matrix in question belongs to a Lie algebra: ordered exponentiation. It is to integration as exponentiation is to multiplication, and permits to go from a Lie algebra element (intuitively, a differential transformation) to a group element (a whole transformation). 
In this case, you need a $n\times n$ matrix-valued function.

It is explained quite well here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential.

Comment: Matrices...*of the same order*...form a vector space. Why this makes that "therefore" appear there is beyond my comprehension, though.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Because addition in that vector space is componentwise (and so is scalar multiplication).

Comment: @geodude. Are you saying that if our matrix belongs to a Lie algebra, then we can define the integral of that matrix using ordered exponentiation? Do you have any further resource links on this subject? I've tried looking online but find either very specialized resources or nothing at all (except for the one link you cite)

Comment: @pbs: Yes, precisely. I have the same problem, there isn't much material to gain insight on that! 
I used such a concept in this answer, if that can help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223024/integral-of-a-curve-with-respect-to-its-curvature/452622#452622
For something in rigor, look here: http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/401130/DejinyMat_29-2007-1_2.pdf.

Comment: I found these related links useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_calculus. Fascinating!

Comment: Apparently there's a book from the seventies called "Product Integration", which is very good. I can't seem to find it anywhere though!

Comment: @geodude In addition to my previous first comment, when I say "...then we can define the integral of that matrix using ordered exponentiation?," I'm asking if we can define the *familiar Newtonian integral* (as in Newtonian calculus) using ordered exponentiation. Or do you mean that an integral of a *different calculus* can be applied, i.e. is ordered exponentiation from a different calculus than that of the Newtonian calculus, so that I can't just swap the usual integral for the "new type" ?

Comment: It is a different integral. Non-Newtonian, if you want. If the matrix belongs to an Abelian Lie group, though, you obtain exactly the exponential of a Newtonian integral, where the integration is carried out in the Lie algebra (which is a nice vector space). 
For example, in physics the angle of rotation is the "integral" of the angular velocity.
Anyway, the integral defined with ordered exponentiation is the so-called "product integral", *not* the one I wrote in the answer.

Comment: @geodude ok, thanks for the heads up. My main interest lies in this Lie Algebra idea, moving the problem of a Newtonian integral of a matrix, where the matrix belongs to a Lie algebra, into some other field of maths which might make the original system of integrals simpler. Thanks for the info.

Comment: In simpler terms, since adding two matrices means adding their components, and since integration is essentially adding an infinite number of infinitesimally small things, you can just integrate the components directly.

Comment: What about the constant of integration?