# Integrate $\int A(x) dx$ where $A(x)=\begin{pmatrix}f_{11}(x)&f_{12}(x)\\ f_{21}(x)&f_{22}(x)\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

Let
\begin{align}
A(x)=\begin{pmatrix}f_{11}(x)&f_{12}(x)\\ f_{21}(x)&f_{22}(x)\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

I am interested in 
\begin{align}
\int A(x) dx
\end{align}
where the integration is done pointwise.

Are there any references that formally define and study properties of this integration?

Comment: I see no reason why the integral of a matrix shouldn't be the matrix of integrals.

Comment: @Arthur  Thanks. I am specifically interested in this example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242394/integrate-int-0-infty-x-ai-1-a-i-frac1cx-dx-where-a-is-psd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral of a matrix is the matrix that has as elements the integrals of the elements (if these elements are integrable functions). See [Integrating a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450560/integrating-a-matrix).

Comment: Why integrability is something that we need to assume. Can the entries be infinities?

Comment: It depends from the kind of integral that you want. There are limited functions that are not Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 1):

All elements can be integrated if it's integrable functions 
therefore 
$$\int A(x)dx$$ 
=$\begin{pmatrix} \int f_{11}(x)& \int f_{12}(x)\\ \int f_{21}(x)& \int f_{22}(x)\end{pmatrix}$