# How do define an integral of a matrix valued function?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

Let $g:\mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$.
How does one define the integral
$$\int_\Gamma g(z) dz,$$
for some closed curve $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{C}$?

Is it understood entry-wise or as an special case of the Bochner Integral? I'm trying to understand the Matrix Cauchy integral formula for the definition of matrix functions.

$$f(A) =  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma f(z)(z I - A)^{-1}dz$$
where $f$ is analytic on and inside a closed contour $\Gamma$ that encloses $\Lambda(A)$.

Comment: The matrix integral is typically just defined component-wise. By linearity, if A is diagonalizable you can move to a basis where A is diagonal and then apply the integral to each of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks @overfullhbox, do you by any chance have a reference for this?

Comment: Not sure, here is another SE post though: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242369/integrate-int-ax-dx-where-ax-beginpmatrixf-11xf-12x-f-21?noredirect=1&lq=1